# Sieve of eratosthenes using dictionaries in python

Tags: python, math, encryption

Below are two forms of the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

---

1) The first is the way I interpreted how to program the Sieve when watching this khan academy video (https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/comp-number-theory/v/sieve-of-eratosthenes-prime-adventure-part-4) this algorithm uses modular division.

---

2) The second has a few modifications I have done to speed up the algorithm including: using a dictionary and deleting composite elements from the dictionary using multiplication to find composites instead of modular division to test them, then creating a sorted list after the sieve is finished.

The second method is much faster, but I had to add a try statement to avoid situations when the function attempts to delete values that have already been deleted, but still deletes elements that are multiples of previous numbers to a power that have not yet been deleted.

The question is, is there any way to avoid values that were already found to be composite instead of using a try statement to skip them, while still using multiplication to locate composites?

```
   def Sieve_2_b(b):
      seq_primes=list()
      c=0
      for i in range(2,(1+b)):
          seq_primes.append(i)
      while (seq_primes[c]**2)<b:
          k=c
          while k<(len(seq_primes)):
              if seq_primes[k]>=(seq_primes[c]**2):
                  if seq_primes[k]%seq_primes[c]==0:
                      del seq_primes[k]
                      k-=1
              k+=1
          c+=1
      return seq_primes

    def Sieve_2_b_using_dict(b):
        seq_primes=list()
        sieve_dict=dict()
        c=0
        for i in range(2,(1+b)):
            seq_primes.append(i)
            sieve_dict[i]=0
        while (seq_primes[c]**2)<b:
            k=c
            while seq_primes[k]<=(b/seq_primes[c]):
                try:
                    del(sieve_dict[(seq_primes[k]*seq_primes[c])])
                except:
                    print(seq_primes[k],seq_primes[c],'stop this')
                    pass
                k+=1
            c+=1
        seq_primes=sorted(sieve_dict,key=sieve_dict.get)
        return seq_primes
```

Comment: The whole point of the Sieve is to eliminate divisions. If you're using division, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769780/python-sieve-of-erastosthenes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary stores a useless value for every key --- it's *always* `0` (which also makes it a lousy key for `sorted`).  Use a set instead.

As a bonus, sets have a method to remove an element *without* raising an exception, regardless of the element's presence in the set.

Here's my first version, mostly copied & pasted from your code:

```py
def sieve_using_set(b):
    seq_primes=list(range(2, b + 1))
    sieve_set=set(range(2, b + 1))
    c=0
    while (seq_primes[c]**2)<b:
        k=c
        while seq_primes[k]<=(b/seq_primes[c]):
            sieve_set.discard(seq_primes[k] * seq_primes[c])
            k+=1
        c+=1
    return list(sorted(sieve_set))
```

It's also much faster.  The speeds were not affected by I/O (I commented out the `print` statement in your "dictionaries" function), nor by excess deletions, since the set version tries to remove the same values your dictionary version did.  The set version has a huge advantage in that it doesn't require a try-except block to *make* those excess deletions.

The next biggest savings I found was using `range` instead of constantly comparing `c` or `k` to some calculation.  I added an `import math` at the top of the file for this:

```py
def sieve_using_set_and_ranges(b):
    seq_primes=list(range(2, b + 1))
    sieve_set=set(range(2, b + 1))
    for c in range(0, math.floor(math.sqrt(b)) + 1):
        for k in range(c, math.floor(b / seq_primes[c]) + 1):
            sieve_set.discard(seq_primes[k] * seq_primes[c])
    return list(sorted(sieve_set))
```

Here's the results of `timeit.Timer.timeit` on 1000 runs of a 1000-long sieve, using an old installation of Python 3.1:

```
Sieve using modular division:
5.98897910118
Sieve using dictionary:
5.10295796394
Sieve using set:
3.10129499435
Sieve using set and ranges:
1.69016003609
```

I used an assertion to prove that the set versions produced the same list output as your two functions.